# Initiate a .click function with "if/else if" statement

Tags: jquery

Apologies for my last question being so poorly made.

In this bit of code I am trying to have a div be able to move left and right when a button is clicked (LButton or RButton)

What I've tried to do is have an initial variable 'click' = 0 and when the button is clicked it adds '1' to the variable. In the if statement the idea is that once the button has been clicked once, it can be clicked again if click = 1 to make the div go an extra 850 px to the left.

This isnt the most practical way of doing this, and I'm not sure if its even semantically correct. Does anyone have a suggestion as to make this work, or perhaps a better way of getting this done?

```
var click=0;
if (click === 2) {
$(function () {
    $('.RButton').click(function (e) {
        $('.slideContain').animate({
            'margin-left': '-2550px'
        });
    });
});
} else if (click === 1) {
$(function () {
    $('.RButton').click(function (e) {
        $('.slideContain').animate({
            'margin-left': '-1700px'
        }); 
    var click = (click + 1);
    });
});
} else if (click === 0) {
$(function () {
    $('.RButton').click(function (e) {
    $('.slideContain').animate({
        'margin-left': '-850px'
    });
    var click = (click+1);
});
}
```

Comment: are you trying to execute #1 *and* #2 on the second click,(and then #1 *and* #2 *and* #3, on the third?) or just #2?

Comment: The idea is that initially the page is at stage 0, and then a button can be clicked to move it to stage 1. At stage 1 the button can again be clicked to move it to stage 2.

Comment: kk try my answer now. if it helps, please "accept" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using an object to correlate which state maps to which position rather than having a chain of `if` statements. Try [this example I wrote on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/UqxNe/). 
I modified the positions slightly just for the demo, but you could easily change them for your situation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var clickState = 0;
    var cssForState = [{
            'margin-left': '0px'
        },{
            'margin-left': '100px'
        },{
            'margin-left': '200px'
        }];

    var advanceToNextClickState = function() {
        clickState++;
        if (clickState >= cssForState.length)
            clickState = 0;
    }

    $('.RButton').click(function (e) {
        console.log("Received click while clickState = " + clickState);
        advanceToNextClickState();
        $('.slideContain').animate(cssForState[clickState]);
    });    
});
```

If you wanted to have another button you could extend this with a second handler, but a more preferred solution would probably be something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/Sjfuv/8/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var clickState = 0;
    var cssForState = [{
            'margin-left': '0px'
        },{
            'margin-left': '100px'
        },{
            'margin-left': '200px'
        }];

    var previousClickState = function() {
        clickState--;
        if (clickState < 0)
            clickState = cssForState.length - 1;
    };

    var nextClickState = function() {
        clickState++;
        if (clickState >= cssForState.length)
            clickState = 0;
    };

    var slideToPosition = function(position) {
        console.log("Sliding to position = " + clickState, cssForState[position]);
        $('.slideContain').animate(cssForState[position]);    
    }

    $('button').click(function (e) {
        console.log("Received click", this, e.target);
        var $button = $(this);
        if ($button.hasClass("LButton"))
            previousClickState();
        else if ($button.hasClass("RButton"))
            nextClickState();
        slideToPosition(clickState);
    });     
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works really well, and the default back to state=0 is more than I had even intended originally. Any help as to how I could add another button to 'reverse' the process? Heres what i tried http://jsfiddle.net/Sjfuv/

Comment: Sure -- BTW, you have a console error in your jsFiddle example: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" -- I'm checking it out right now

Comment: Looks like you had a minor typo -- `clickstate` is not the same as `clickState` (capital S) so that's why `clickstate--` did not decrease `clickState`. Also there were some empty parentheses `();` for which I think you forgot to put the function name `previousClickState`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind event handlers inside if statements, put if statements inside event handlers.

```
$('.RButton').click(function (e) {

    if (someCondition) {
        $('.slideContain').animate({
            'margin-left': '-2550px'
        });
        //update state here
    } else if (someOtherCondition) {
        $('.slideContain').animate({
            'margin-left': '-1700px'
        });
        //update state here
    } else {
        $('.slideContain').animate({
            'margin-left': '-850px'
        });
        //update state here
    }

});
```

I've left it up to you on how to keep track of the current state and what needs to happen when the button is clicked, but this should push you in the right direction.

Also note that when you define a variable using `var` inside a function, you create a new instance, and don't use the globally-scoped instance.

Answer (score 0):

it wont work replace `var click = (click+1);` with `click++;` and it will run fine.

there is no reason to create a new variable, and it simply wont work.

also change `if (click3 === x)` to `if (click % 3 === x)`, this will allow it to wrap-around - time #4 will execute action #1, and #8 will execute #2 etc.

also place all your code, except your `var click = 0;` inside one big

```
$('.RButton').click(function (e) {
}
```

Comment: That was an error I forgot to change, doesnt change the outcome of the code however (talking about the click2 stuff) I changed it all to just "click", that should work right>

Comment: @user2356594 sorry bout that, didnt read carefully enough, check edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.RButton').click(function (e) {
    $('.slideContain').animate({
        if(click == 2)
        'margin-left': '-2550px'
         if(click == 1)
        'margin-left': '-1770px'
         if(click == 0)
        'margin-left': '-850px'
    });
```

Simple and elegant. Please use if conditions inside the click event.